# How to convert images of gif picture to NSData for iOS?

Tags: ios, nsdata, sdwebimage

In my iOS Application, I want to show a Gif image in my `tableViewCell`. Download this Gif image by `SDWebImage`, and use `FLAnimatedImageView` to show this image.

But now I have a problem, `SDWebImage` return a images ，but the `FLAnimatedImageView` want a `NSData`.

How to convert images of `gif` to `NSData`？

Forgive my poor English.

```
[[SDWebImageManager sharedManager] downloadImageWithURL:url options:0 progress:nil completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, BOOL finished, NSURL *imageURL) {
            if (image.images.count > 0)//gif
            {
                // how to get the data
                FLAnimatedImage *animatedImage = [FLAnimatedImage animatedImageWithGIFData:data];
                _chatGIFImage.animatedImage = animatedImage1;
            }

        }];
```

Comment: You can directly use gif image by using SDwebimage lib

Comment: I found that "UIImage+GIF.h"  has a method:
 "+ (UIImage *)sd_animatedGIFWithData:(NSData *)data;" 
how to get a  reversed method? convert  gif image to NSData.

Comment: @Jigar Tarsariya  I have already used SDwebimage to display gif picture，but it has huge memory leaks , two 2M gif pictures can bring 200M memory leaks online，application crash easily ，I think my happy life will not be longer, my boss will punish me ./(ㄒoㄒ)/~~

Comment: Ohhhk... Then you have to find that way to convert your gif image to NSData.. :)

Comment: @Jigar Tarsariya yes, I was tortured for a day.

Comment: Don't give up man..Just go ahead..You will find solution also...Let me try that also

Answer (score 1):

If you have the URL of the image you can directly use the following to convert it to NSData

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: imageURL];
```

Comment: `dataWithContentsOfURL` will block the thread on which it is called as this is a synchronous method. You should not call this on the main thread as it will block the app for tens of seconds on a slow network.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like below:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

    NSError* error = nil;
    NSData* ImageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:yourIMGUrl options:NSDataReadingUncached error:&error];
    if (error) {

        NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);

    } else {

        NSLog(@"successfull.");

        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            FLAnimatedImage *animatedImage = [FLAnimatedImage animatedImageWithGIFData:ImageData];
            _chatGIFImage.animatedImage = animatedImage1;

        });
    }


});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can simply use

```
// UIImageJPEGRepresentation(<#UIImage * _Nonnull image#>, <#CGFloat compressionQuality#>)
NSData *data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0);
```

Compression quality can be between 0.0 (high compression, low quality) and 1.0 (low compression, high quality)

Comment: This does not get NSData in a GIF format for use with FLAnimatedImage.